# Import an image as a reference to a plane but the image i am getting is lying on a another plane

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I import an image as a reference on a top ortho plane,but the image i am getting is on a another plane and the plane which i selected is blank.What i do to get it on a reference plane. [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that helps but usually when you insert reference Images they get inserted the way you are looking right now.
So let me explain.
If you tap 1 on you Num-Pad and insert a reference Image it should appear in the XZ-Plane.
So maybe toggle to your desired view and try to insert your reference that way.

I am not sure if it is possible to get a reference Image to a plane...
You could assign the image to the Plane as a Material but I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: With Shift + A > _Add_ > _Image_ you can choose from 1. Reference, 2. Background or 3. Images as Planes.